# Why does this javascript NOT work on Windows 8.1's IE11? (It works on the latest version of Firefox, Chrome, even Windows 7's IE11)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

This piece of javascript works on the latest version of Firefox, Chrome, even Windows 7's IE11.

However, for some reason, on Windows 8.1's IE11 and only on Windows 8.1's IE11, it doesn't execute properly.

```
$('[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function(){
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('animated flipInY');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.tab-pane').addClass('animated flipInY');
    },
    10);
});
```

Link to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z9x6/2/

The CSS transition is from animate.css http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/. It works flawlessly on modern web browsers; it's not the issue. The issue is with my javascript.

**Edit#1:** Apparently the stupid thing works properly when I zoom in (over 100%); and half work when zoom out (less than 100%).  It just doesn't work at 100%. Can I tag this as weirdest bug ever? xD

**Edit #2:** And even when zoomed in over 100%, it doesn't work if inside a container div with fixed width.

Comment: Are there any errors in the IE11 console(press F12)?

Comment: How about one of the other browser modes (like IE10 mode in IE11)? That might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @scragar No error in console: [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/e4e4syc.png)

Comment: @JoeEnos Used emulation mode set to IE10, still same issue.

Comment: Just ran it on WIN7/IE11 and Win8.1/IE11 -- The code JavasScript itself seems to be running properly, but under Win8.1, the animation isn't running.  It just does a boring image switch.  Odd -- the 'flipInY' of the animate.css demo page *does* work,, however.  http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Thanks for confirming. I'd also like to add that the CSS itself works when I manually add the classes in, even in Windows 8.1's IE11.  It's just for some reason refuse to work when I add the animation classes via that javascript--on Win8.1's IE11 only. I never know that there are such differences in Win7's IE11 and Win8.1's IE11, haha. GG, Microsoft, making web development just that little bit harder since IE6, xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahah!

I tracked this one down, kinda-sorta.

Your code actually works.  However, for some reason the Win8.1/IE11 combo takes more *screen space* to actually execute that animation.

So, load your code again, then use the Control-Minus key and shrink the text as small as you can until you can just make out your navigation buttons.  Click on your front and back and you'll notice the animation does run.

Comment: Adding on to this . . . apparently it works properly when I zoom in (over 100%).